# Is there a PHP library that can interpolate parameters into an SQL query?

Tags: php, postgresql

Is there a PHP library that can bind parameters to an SQL query?

It should:

- support named parameters (instead of positional)
- have the ability to return the final query (I'm stating this explicitly because PDO can't do it even with client-side emulation enabled.)
- be smart enough to not replace placeholders inside strings and comments
- be able to bind arrays to IN clauses

If it's a pure PHP library, it doesn't have to support *all* of those because I can just add missing features. With PDO I can't do that without recompiling PHP.

If it matters, it's mainly intended for PostgreSQL.

Comment: sounds easy, why dont you write this function instead of looking for libraries

Comment: @meda Because it isn't easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at MeekroDB library. It's MySQL wrapper, but i think what it's not wery difficult to rewrite it to PostgreSQL. It has printf-like format of passing query variables as strings, digits and arrays, and also have methods like insert and update.

Answer (score 0):

You might try googling for php orm. Orm stands for object relational mapper. Regardless of language, an orm is a framework for converting in-memory data to on-disk persisted objects, generally in the form of a table row in a database.